# Flutter: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'

Tags: dart, flutter

I am developing a simple todo app using flutter.

The app has multiple Views and tables (SQLite).

1. Todo (StatelessWidget)
2. Tag (StatefulWidget)

In the case of Todo ui, it works fine, but Tag ui doesn't work.

First code is Todo ui. (works fine).

```dart
class TodosPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final TodoRepository _todoRepository;
  final TodosBloc bloc;

  TodosPage(this._todoRepository) : this.bloc = TodosBloc(_todoRepository);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: StreamBuilder<List<Todo>>(
            stream: bloc.todos,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null) {
                return Text("Empty");
              }

              return ListView(
                children: snapshot.data.map(_buildItem).toList(),
              );
            }),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildItem(Todo todo) => Text(todo.name);
```

and here is Tag ui (It doesn't work).

```dart
class TagsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final TagRepository _tagRepository;

  TagsPage(this._tagRepository);

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _TagsState(_tagRepository);
}

class _TagsState extends State<TagsPage> {
  final TagRepository _tagRepository;
  final TagsBloc bloc;

  _TagsState(this._tagRepository) : this.bloc = TagsBloc(_tagRepository);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: StreamBuilder<List<Tag>>(
            stream: bloc.tags,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data.isEmpty) {
                print("[TagsPage][JOS] build - snapshot.data is null");
              } else {
                return ListView(
                  children: snapshot.data.map(_buildTagItem).toList(),
                );
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      );

  _buildTagItem(Tag tag) => Text(tag.name);
}
```

and the TagBloc is here:

```dart
class TagsBloc {
  final TagRepository _tagRepository;
  final _getTagsSubject = PublishSubject<List<Tag>>();

  Stream<List<Tag>> get tags => _getTagsSubject.stream;

  TagsBloc(this._tagRepository) {
    _getTags();
  }

  Future<Null> _getTags() async {
    await _tagRepository.getAll().then((list) {
      _getTagsSubject.add(list);
    });
  }
}
```

When I run, Tag ui show the below error log:

```
04-07 00:13:45.698 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
04-07 00:13:45.708 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter: The following assertion was thrown building StreamBuilder<List<Tag>>(dirty, dependencies:
04-07 00:13:45.708 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter: [_LocalizationsScope-[GlobalKey#49b9d], _InheritedTheme], state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<List<Tag>,
04-07 00:13:45.708 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter: AsyncSnapshot<List<Tag>>>#65ac3):
04-07 00:13:45.708 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Widget>'
04-07 00:13:45.715 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter: Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
04-07 00:13:45.715 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter: more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
04-07 00:13:45.715 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter: In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
04-07 00:13:45.715 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter:   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md
04-07 00:13:45.715 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter: When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
04-07 00:13:45.724 25181-25195/com.youknow.jos I/flutter: #0      _TagsState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:jos/pages/tags.dart:49:62)
```

The Todo and Tag has no difference.
I think the only difference is StatefulWidget/StatelessWidget.
I don't know how can I resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared a return type on `_buildTagItem`. Change this:

```
  _buildTagItem(Tag tag) => Text(tag.name);
```

to this:

```
  Widget _buildTagItem(Tag tag) => Text(tag.name);
```

As a result, your `map(...).toList()` returns `List<dynamic>` instead of `List<Widget>` - hence the error.

Comment: @yoonhok always try to stick with data types(Power of statically typed languges), so that you know whats going on in compile time. I think you have encouter a great example for that.